# detect window.opener window refresh event

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, window, refresh

suppose on window A I do

```
var newWindow = window.open('url', 'name', 'width=100');
```

and open a new window (call it window B)

then on window B I get a reference to the opener window (window A)

```
var opener = $(window.opener)
```

is there a way to use the opener variable above to detect from window B when window A gets refreshed and/or finished refreshing?

Comment: 1) How does this differ from your original question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269535/detecting-the-existence-of-window-after-reload? 2) Maybe poll `opener` from window B in intervals for a variable or something else and if it change, make window B known to window A (this is in theory).

Comment: What do you mean by refresh? You want to detect if someone refreshes window A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can detect is when the opener unloads by using e.g:

```
$(opener).unload()
```

Inside newWindow you should be able to re-assign the variable inside the opener after a  timeout.

Don't forget to re-assign the unload-function too after the reload.

I've made a DEMO: http://fiddle.jshell.net/doktormolle/2Pcn8/show/

Sources:
opener: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/2Pcn8/
newWindow: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/jB9D6/

Works for me in IE(6-9),FF,Chrome,Safari.
Did not work in Opera

Comment: hmm that doesn't seem to work in Internet Explorer (I used 9)

Answer (score 0):

I'd set a variable in the original window, perhaps a timestamp or something similar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var datime = Date();
});
```

Then in window B, you could do the same thing, and based on the creation dates of the two windows, you would know if window A was refreshed recently or not.   You could also store the creation date of window A as a variable in window B, so that you would know anytime window A has been refreshed.